# package libwebp6 version 0.6.1-2.1+deb11u1 was detected in APT package manager on a container image running Debian 11.7 is vulnerable to CVE-2023-4863

Tags: c#, azure, kubernetes, dockerfile, debian

Created Dockerfile for .Net Core React.js and Redux application

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y libpng-dev libjpeg-dev curl libxi6 build-essential libgl1-mesa-glx
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y libpng-dev libjpeg-dev curl libxi6 build-essential libgl1-mesa-glx
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ProjectSPA1/ProjectSPA1.csproj", "ProjectSPA1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ProjectSPA1/ProjectSPA1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ProjectSPA1"
RUN dotnet build "ProjectSPA1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ProjectSPA1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ProjectSPA1.dll"]
```

Deployed in azure kubernetes working fine. But detected vulnerable saying

> package libwebp6 version 0.6.1-2.1+deb11u1 was detected in APT package manager on a container image running Debian 11.7 is vulnerable to CVE-2023-4863

How to fix it. Thanks!

I try to remove the package libwebp6. but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

According to the **Debian Security Tracker**, this package is indeed vulnerable to **CVE-2023-4863** Check this [link](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2023-4863)

I tried in my environment with same package that which you used and having many issues with it.

**For example:**

[image]

- Please check the latest version of [**`libwebp6 (0.6.1-2.1+deb11u2)`**](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/libwebp6)
  [image]

**Dockerfile :**

```
# Stage 1: Build the .NET Core application
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the .NET Core project files and restore dependencies
COPY YourApp/YourApp.csproj ./YourApp/
RUN dotnet restore ./YourApp/YourApp.csproj

# Copy the entire project and build the application
COPY . .
WORKDIR /app/YourApp
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Stage 2: Build the React.js frontend
FROM node:14 AS frontend
WORKDIR /app/client-app

# Copy the React.js application files and install dependencies
COPY client-app/package.json .
COPY client-app/package-lock.json .
RUN npm install

# Copy the React.js application source code
COPY client-app/src ./src
COPY client-app/public ./public

# Build the React.js application
RUN npm run build

# Stage 3: Build the runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/YourApp/out ./

# Install libwebp6
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libwebp6=0.6.1-2.1+deb11u2

# Copy the React.js build from the frontend stage
COPY --from=frontend /app/client-app/build ./wwwroot

# Expose the port your application will run on (adjust as needed)
EXPOSE 80

# Set the entry point for your .NET Core application
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "YourApp.dll"]
```

[image]

Deployed in azure kubernetes:

[image]

[image]